# How Angular DI finds constructor parameter types at runtime?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection

How Angular DI finds constructor parameter types at runtime?

```
@Injectable()
class Service1 {
  constructor(dep1: MyClass) {...}
}
```

When injecting Service1 somewhere, Angular firstly should resolve *dep1* through DI.
how Angular finds out that the type of *dep1* is **MyClass** at runtime?
(I want to do something similar at runtime. I've a function and I want to know its parameter types at run time).